# Craft custom, separate legend for geom_abline

Tags: r, ggplot2

I realize there are many similarly-titled queries out there, but I have looked through many and none seem to solve my particular problem. Happy to be wrong on this, though.

Here's some code and the plot it makes:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(12345)
types <- c("a", "b")[sample(rep(1:2, each = 5))]
Data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), 
                   y = rnorm(10), 
                   Type = types)

p1 <- ggplot(Data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = Type), size = 2.5) +
  geom_abline(aes(slope = 0, intercept = 1, colour = "A cool line"), lty = "dotted", lwd = 1.5) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour = Type), lwd = 1.5) + 
  ggtitle("abline legend plz")
```

[image: plot generated from the sample code]

This is an ok plot, but I need a few things to change:

1. No linetype indicators in the legend boxes (also, whhyy are the a/b legend lines displaying the "dotted" linetype?)
2. I would like the legend for "A cool line" to appear separately, in a new legend, but in the same format as the other legend
3. Bonus points: no point-type indicators in *any* of the legend boxes.

Here's an MS paint rendering of the legend column of my dreams:

[image]

Some notes:

- If linetype is indicated in the 2nd legend, that's not a huge deal. But I definitely don't want it in the first legend.
- In the example, I set other things like `lwd` and `size` because I need to in what I'm doing. My solution needs to allow for those to be set manually and separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your horizontal dotted line is always horizontal, I'd use:

```
p1 <- ggplot(Data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
          geom_point(aes(colour = Type), size = 2.5) +
          geom_line(aes(colour = Type), lwd = 1.5) + 
          geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 1, linetype = "A cool line"), colour = "darkgreen", lwd = 1.5) + 
          scale_colour_discrete(name = "Type") +
          scale_linetype_manual(name = "A cool (custom) title", 
                                values = c("A cool line" = "dotted")) + 
          ggtitle("abline legend plz")  + 
          guides(colour   = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = NA)),
                 linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = "solid")))
```

This forces the dark green line in the legend to be horizontal. Here's the result:
[image]

If however you want to use `geom_abline()` because your dotted line might have a slope, you'd replace the

```
geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 1, linetype = "A cool line"), colour = "darkgreen", lwd = 1.5) +
```

part with

```
geom_abline(aes(slope = 0, intercept = 1, linetype = "A cool line"), colour = "darkgreen", lwd = 1.5) +
```

which however would replace the the dark green line in the legend with a sloped line. Nice question, by the way!